# Can I extend lisp with c++?

Tags: c++, lisp, extend

Can I call a function from lisp from a library written in c or c++? How can I extend lisp?
This is useful when you want to do some system calls or stuff like that.

Comment: Can I extend my Porsche with a go-kart engine? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is unusual to call non-lisp code from lisp, and rarely necessary. CLX (the X11 client implementation for CL) doesn't link to the Xlib implementation but "speaks" X11 directly. On any system, your CL implementation is likely to already have excellent operating system hooks rendering this unnecessary.

That said, the answer depends on the lisp implementation:

In [ECL](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/) you can actually host a CL environment under C and simply call `cl_eval()` with the code to execute. This can let you write your application (or application host) in C (or C++) and "call to" lisp code.

In [CCL](http://www.clozure.com/clozurecl.html), there is a C-compatible calling interface which lets you do something like this:

```
(with-cstrs ((x "Hello World"))
  (#_puts x))
```

In most other CL implementations (like SBCL; and yes this works in ECL and CCL as well) you can use UFFI (or CFFI) which simply lets you call C functions, which is what other people are talking about. If this is all you want to do, then CFFI is a good, safe place to start.

Comment: Lots of programs still target uffi instead of cffi; uffi still has greater availability.

Comment: These days CFFI supports more Lisps than UFFI, namely ABCL and CLISP. Not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: *These* days is now 2012, and not 2008 when I wrote that :P

Answer (score 5):

See [UFFI](http://uffi.b9.com/) and [CFFI](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/) and the [slicker Clozure FFI](http://trac.clozure.com/openmcl/wiki/OpenMclFfi)

Answer (score 4):

[CFFI](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/)!